# Excel Pivot Table - Display values of multiple fields as percentage of parent total in one step

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am attempting to display values as percentage of parent total for multiple columns in one click. This doesn't seem to be possible. I have to go column by column and make the selection. Is there any way to shortcut this process?

Answer (score 0):

> I have to go column by column and make the selection. Is there any way to shortcut this process?

No, there is no batch-edit or multi-edit in Excel pivot table. You might find a workaround with macros.